# How do I group dates in IBM COGNOS when building a front end dashboard

Tags: date, group-by, cognos

I am an extreme newbie to COGNOS (5 days give or take a few hrs) and have been thrown in the deep end.
I have a data package i am working with and the only date field I can use has the property of timestamp. I have looked through other questions that are similar and i have used the "CAST" function to turn the field into a date so this has worked.

cast ( [TR_Logical Layer].[Fact Event].[Period Datetime],DATE) - so I was happy with that.

However now when I am building the graph, I am getting repeated dates - and I can only think that this is because somehow it is still holding onto the timestamp portion of the field.
Please how can i get all of my many dates for say the 21st Jul to be one?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using the GO Sales (query) package and post the report spec?

Comment: You seem to have taken the date from one of your fact tables.  

I really don't believe that in a properly designed data warehouse that this is the only date column you have available.

It is probable that you are getting multiple dates as the casting of the datetime to date is removing the time bit but there's still multiple records for each date.

These time values 

2021-08-01 18:15
2021-08-01 17:30
2021-08-01 10:21

when cast to date will produce

2021-08-01
2021-08-01
2021-08-01

You want to group those values.

Comment: You don't mention the usage of the calculation which you are creating. You don't mention what the SQL which is generated looks like.  Those two sentences are related to the last one of the first comment.

This sort of thing is best done in the modelling tool as it is modelling.  The reporting side of things should be just a matter of throwing a bunch of objects onto the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issue: Repeating is probably due to how it is grouped (down to the time which would have the day repeating)

Suggested solution: Add a determinant to control granularity and grouping

Here are the steps
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=determinants-specifying

1. Click the query subject you want, and click Actions, Edit Definition.
2. Click the Determinants tab.
3. Click Add under the Determinants box.
   The entry New Determinant displays in the box. To give this entry a meaningful name, right-click it, and click Rename.
4. To define a key, right-click a query item in the Available items box and click Add as Key. Tip: You can also drag query items to the Key box.
5. To identify which query items should be associated with this determinant, right-click query items in the Available items box, and click Add as Attributes.
   Tip: You can also drag query items to the Attributes box.
   You can have a determinant with no attributes defined for it. Framework Manager uses this type of determinant to indicate which query items are indexed.
6. To specify that the selected determinant should be used as the unique identifier, select the Uniquely Identified check box.
   Do this only if the data in this item is unique for every row in the underlying data source. You can specify more than one unique determinant if they are truly unique. At query time, the relationship being used will determine which unique determinant to use.
7. Select the Group By check box to indicate that when keys or attributes associated with that determinant are repeated in the data, IBM® Cognos® Analytics should apply aggregate functions and grouping to avoid double-counting.
8. If you want to change the order of the determinants, use the arrow buttons.
   Determinants are processed in the order in which they are specified in the model.
9. Click OK